problem building new project
Hello i have Apple M2 Pro, with a local solana-test-validator running. I created new wallet and i can airdrop sol and check my balance.
solana-cli 1.17.25
rustup 1.27.1 (54dd3d00f 2024-04-24)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active rustc version is rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)
in my .zshrc file i have :
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/myuser/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana"
I create a new project: anchor init counter.
Now im trying to build the project:
cargo build: This commands finished with success but inside target i dont see a deploy folder with .so file.
anchor build and cargo build-bpf: error: no such command: +solana
Cargo does not handle +toolchain directives.
Did you mean to invoke cargo through rustup instead?
Please I need help to start coding and move forward on my learning proccess!
Thank you.

Does this answer your question? anchor build isn't working properly
